# Django Rest Framework trying to get similar products with serializer reversed

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i`m new to DRF and im trying to serialize similar product on product.
heres my code

***models.py***

```
class Product(models.Model): 
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="products")
    tag = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    sell_limit = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)



class SimilarProduct(models.Model):
    on_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="on_products")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="products")
```

***serializers.py***

```
class ProductDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    similar = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

in serializers i have written this type of code which dont works.
#CODE :

```
    def get_similar(self, obj):
        product_query = Product.objects.filter(pk__in=obj.on_products.values_list("id"))
        return ProductListSerializer(product_query, many=True).data
```

and heres my ProductListSerializer

```
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

i want to get similar products of product but it dont works.
any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Did you add model in the serializer ?

Comment: @Nika110 can you show what json you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `SerializerMethodField` you can directly use `SimilarProductSerializer` with `many=True`:

```
class SimilarProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SimilarProduct
        fields = ['category', 'price']
```

```
class ProductDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    products = SimilarProductSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'products']
```

I think you can also change the related name of the product field of the `SimilarProduct` model, this will be more clear and you can access `similiar_products` of the `Product` object by `product.similar_products`.

```
class SimilarProduct(models.Model):
    on_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="on_products")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="smilar_products")
```